# AngularJS displaying MongoDB data

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I've a problem with the interact of AngularJS and MongoDb.
I use NodeJS and ExpressJS on the server-side. With Mongoose I talk to Mongo.
I've just done the routes.

index.js

```
      app.get('/api/dashboard', function (req, res) {

    Homepage
        .find({}, 'title -_id createdBy allbids.bid endTime')
        .exec(function (err, auctions) {
            if(err)
                res.send(err);
            console.log(auctions);
            res.json(auctions);
        })
});
```

The console display all the fields that i need.

Then I pass on the front-end. I use Angular route in this way:

```
       var app = angular.module('auction', [ 'ngRoute','HomeCtrl','NewAuctionCtrl', 'FollowingAuctionsCtrl', 'MyAuctionsCtrl']);


      app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
 {

 $routeProvider

.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/partials/dashboard.html',
    controller: 'HomeController'
})



$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);


});
```

And my HomeController is this:

```
    angular.module('HomeCtrl', [])
  .controller('HomeController',function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('/api/dashboard').then(function(data) {
       console.log(data);
       $scope.auctions= data;

     })
  });
```

In the dashboard.html

```
         <div class="panel panel-default" ng-controller="HomeController">
<div class="panel-heading">All The Auctions</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="auction in HomeController.auctions">
            {{auction}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It doesn't work. I need only to use `{{auction.title}}` instead of `{{auction}}`??

Comment: Change to be "auction in auctions". You shouldn't need to reference your controller as you're using $scope.
Edit: then like you commented get the title like {{auction.title}}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is being successfully fetched from the server, you can do

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-controller="HomeController">
  <div class="panel-heading">All The Auctions</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="auction in auctions">
          {{auction}}
        </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
```

It doesn't need to be HomeController.auctions. This will put the entire auction object into that `li`, so depending on what you're trying to do you may want to do something like `{{auction.title}}` as you mentioned

Comment: I did how you said but it doesn't work. With {{auction.title}} it shows me nothing, with {{auction}} it shows me an array with 5 elements, 1 are the data, all desplayed together, the others are status code, and functions that i don't know

Comment: In your controller you probably need to do $scope.auctions = data.data; instead of just $scope.auctions = data;

Answer (score 0):

Since you have declare to use HomeController in the outtest `<div>` that cover you heading and ui, li, that area will bind $scope in HomeController automactically.

So just use `{{auction in auctions}}`. If you have another $scope like `$scope.foo = "foo"` in HomeController, you can try `<div>{{foo}}</div>` inside the `<div ng-controller="HomeController"` to get the idea

I'm not sure if you want to separate the modules and inject it in to your *auction* module, that have .config() or if you just need HomeController to be one of controllers in *action*'s module.

If your intention is the second one, I suggest to use `var app = angular.module('auction',['ngRoute']).config( bla bla )`

and in HomeController, use `angular.module('auction').controller('HomeController',function ($scope, $http) { bla bla })` so you don't have to inject new controller everytime you create new controller

Hope it helps